# python best way to determine time ranges

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, range

Forgive a novice question, but I have the following snippet in code:

```
timePeriod = '7'
timeDiff = today - dateLast
if timeDiff.days > 90:
    timePeriod = '180'
elif timeDiff.days > 30:
    timePeriod = '90'
elif timeDiff.days > 7:
    timePeriod = '30'
# Use timePeriod in call...
```

And it just seems terribly inefficient.  There must be a better way to assign timePeriod using the datetime library, but I haven't found one.  Part of the problem is that the code is so generic, searching for answers yields thousands of unrelated results.  I've contemplated:

```
timePeriod = '180' if timeDiff.days > 90 else '90' if timeDiff.days > 30 else...
```

But this doesn't utilize the power of python that I've seen elsewhere.

Is there an obvious 'correct' solution here that I'm not seeing?  Or is my original solution 'good enough' and I shouldn't be messing with it?

Much thanks!

Comment: What does `timePeriod` variable mean? What does it measure?

Comment: It's a string, needed to access the correct link within a page scraper I'm automating.

Comment: why do you think its terribly inefficient ? just a gut feeling? It may not be very pretty ... but I suspect its fast enough ... also this should probably go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: in that case, I agree with @JoranBeasley

Comment: to support *many* intervals, you could put values into a sorted list and use `bisect` module to search values in it. Something like: `"7 30 90 180".split()[bisect.bisect([0, 7, 30, 90], (today - dateLast).days))]` (not tested, you might need to change it).

Comment: I guess you'd have to see it in context, it's definitely the least compact/"pretty" code in the function, and although it works, I'm left with the gut feeling that 'there must be a better way to do this'.  The subtext of the question is my overall education in python, as I'm certain that I'll be doing similar time frame comparisons in the future.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's definitely in the right direction, (if I understand correctly) you're using the difference to select from an array.. But does datetime do something similar internally?

Comment: @Derek_6424246: Provide the description in plain English of what is the intent of your code. It is not clear what is "something similar" in this case.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian To further elaborate: without reading the bisect documentation, I gather that using bisect you're placing the timeDiff within an ordered array, and bisect returns an index which can then be used to reference the string array.  Similarly, it seems like some function should exist in datetime which will tell you where your date falls within a set of ranges.

Comment: @Derek_6424246: My guess is that `7` is a week, `30` is a "month", `180` is a quarter so that the sequence is not arbitrary. But, no, there is no builtin in datetime way that does: `bisect.bisect([0, 7, 30, 90], (today - dateLast).days))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I went with your suggestion, see above.

Comment: @Derek_6424246: if you found the answer then post it as an answer and accept it. Don't put it in the question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking." -- If you'd like to answer, I'd be happy to give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hat tip to J.F. Sebastian who pointed me in this direction.  To anyone who's interested in the solution I went with:

```
from bisect import bisect
...
periods = [0, 7, 30, 90, 180]
timeDiff = (today - dateLast).days
timePeriod = str(periods[bisect(periods[:-1], timeDiff)])
```

This is tested for all positive values of timeDiff (the [:-1] caps the result to '180', prevents out of bounds reference).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for "beautiful" code, you could do something like this (the idea, in general, is to compose your conditions into some kind of data structure that you can iterate through)

```
timeDiff = (today - dateLast).days
timePeriod = next(p for p, expr in (('180', timeDiff > 90),
                                    ('90', timeDiff > 30),
                                    ('30', timeDiff > 7),
                                    ('7', True))
                  if expr)
# Use timePeriod in call...
```

This may or may not be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tuple. Where tup[0] will represent the `timeDiff` in days and tup[1] represents the `timePeriod` to be set.

```
tup = ( (90, 180), (30, 90), (7, 30) )
for t in tup:
    if timeDiff.days > tup[0]:
        timePeriod = tup[1]
        break
```

It would be a lot smaller but im not sure about efficiency.